# How does appengine NDB Asynchronous Operation eventloop work?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, asynchronous, app-engine-ndb

I'm using python runtime on **The App Engine Standard Environment**.

I'm using some async operations in my code, quotes from tutorial:

- > You might be able to speed up your application by performing
  >   Datastore actions in parallel with other things, or performing a few
  >   Datastore actions in parallel with each other.
- > Tasklets are a way to write concurrent functions without threads;
  >   tasklets are executed by an event loop

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async

It's all about parallel execution, but I don't understand how does this parallelism work in synchronous python code.

How does eventloop work? Does it run in separate process/thread?
Does it perform any really-concurrent executions? Or it is just convenient way to create batched rpcs, which run synchronously on first `get_result()` call?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected async op is just a way to create and launch multiple RPCs (which may or may not be batched, it's not mandatory) before blocking on the first (and each of all subsequent) `get_result()` calls. And this applies to most/all of the RPC-based GAE infra (ndb, memcache, urlfetch, etc)

If you look at the implementations of the non-async versions of most of the calls (which support async versions) you'll see they're really just the async version calls immediately followed by the `get_result()` call, for example:

```
  @classmethod
  def _get_or_insert(*args, **kwds):
    """Transactionally retrieves an existing entity or creates a new one.    
    (snip)          
    """
    cls, args = args[0], args[1:]
    return cls._get_or_insert_async(*args, **kwds).get_result()
  get_or_insert = _get_or_insert
```

As for running the event loop itself - it looks like it is launched transparently when your app makes your first `ndb` RPC call (of the request/thread), via `get_event_loop()`:

```
def get_event_loop():
  """Return a EventLoop instance.

  A new instance is created for each new HTTP request.  We determine
  that we're in a new request by inspecting os.environ, which is reset
  at the start of each request.  Also, each thread gets its own loop.
  """
  ev = _state.event_loop
  if not os.getenv(_EVENT_LOOP_KEY) and ev is not None:
    ev.clear()
    _state.event_loop = None
    ev = None
  if ev is None:
    ev = EventLoop()
    _state.event_loop = ev
    os.environ[_EVENT_LOOP_KEY] = '1'
  return ev
```

Answer (score 0):

Google appengine provides a way to run asynchronous methods, by using @ndb.tasklet  wrapper.

Any python method wrapped with @ndb.tasklet, will return a future object upon execution.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

@ndb.tasklet
def sum_async(a, b):
    raise ndb.Return(a+b)

result = sum_async(1,2) # "result" will contain future object instead of original answer 3
```

When the `sum_async()` method is called it will return a `ndb.future` object. To get the actual result from this method we can use `sum_async(1,2).get_result()`.

But if the function is a generator of the form:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

@ndb.tasklet
def generic_sum_async(*agrs):
    result= sum(*args)
    raise ndb.Return(result)

@ndb.tasklet
def sum_async_generator(a,b):
    result = yield generic_sum(a,b)
    raise ndb.Return(result)

sum_result = sum_async_generator(a,b) # Will return a future object which is inserted into eventloop.
```

When the `sum_async_generator()` method is called, it will return a future object just like the previous example, but this time `sum_async_generator()` is a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python). If an async method is a generator, it will insert the method's future object into the `event_loop` (in eventloop class this is referred as `current` queue). When the `.get_result()` method is called on this future object, the event loop will start executing the futures inside it and upon completion it will set the result for this parent future object.

If the asynchronous metho contains only computational operations, the execution time will be similar to doing the same operations synchronously in python methods. But the major advantage comes when we are making RPC calls inside the asynchronous methods.

```
@ndb.tasklet
def rpc_async_method():
    a = yield method1()
    rpc_result = yield rpc_call_to_read_from_database()
    b = yield method2()
    raise ndb.Return(a,b,rpc_result)
```

From the above pseudo code, if the `rpc_async_method()` is not asynchronous, then the program execution will wait at `rpc_call_to_read_from_database()` method until it gets completed. After that execution will move to `method2()`.
But for the asynchronous cases, the eventloop will identify and enqueue the rpc related methods in a separate queue (in eventloop class it is referred as `rpcs = {}` follwed by internal eventloop logic) so that its execution will not block the other asynchronous methods executing below it.

`ndb.tasklet` also has a `multiFuture` through which we can execute multiple asynchronous methods in parallel as below:

```
futs = [async_method_1(), async_method_2(), async_method_3()]
yield futs
```

In this way google appengine has overridden the `yield` and `raise` operators to perform the asynchronous operations in python.

To check how any asynchronous method will get executed in event loop, I have provided an decorator in this library: https://github.com/Manas-Chinta/google_appengine_extensions.

This [@ELTracer()](https://github.com/Manas-Chinta/google_appengine_extensions) decorator will observe the event loop and print whenever any future (generator or rpc related futures) is added to eventloop or any future is under execution from eventloop.